# kill the General-Purpose tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Can we kill the [general-purpose](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-purpose) tag? Its use is pretty general (pun intended) and seems to be a collection of older questions ranging from bad to acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

Seems reasonable to me.  Of the 12 that are currently tagged, only one didn't have other tags that boxed the question better.  For the one that only has one tag, it's a pretty bad question that should be re-tagged to something else.  I would have re-tagged it, but I am afraid to edit and then bump the question to the front page without a moderator first closing it.

For any moderators dropping in on this thread, here's the errant question.  I have also flagged the question for moderator review.
[Is programming a SubCulture?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/12343/53019)

Comment: That pretty much why I posted this a lot of the questions I don't really want to bump, especially when open

Comment: @Ryathal - Maple Shaft closed the question, so I went ahead and re-tagged it.  1 down.  A few more to go.